# Moving a button in VB6

Tags: vb6

Is it possible in visual basic to have a button that you can move with a mouse drag, which stays on the same horizontal line and only moves a certain distance each way. Something like the balance control on the sound for a computer

Comment: From the description of what you want to do I wonder if you should be using the horizontal scrollbar control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example to drag a button named Command1. To limit the distance it can move, just add some conditions to the DragOver event:

```
Dim blnDrag As Boolean
Private Sub Command1_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Not blnDrag Then
        blnDrag = True
        Command1.Drag
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Command1_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Command1.DragMode = vbnone
    blnDrag = False
End Sub
Private Sub Form_DragOver(Source As Control, X As Single, Y As Single, State As Integer)
    Command1.Left = X
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Command1.DragMode = vbManual
End Sub
```